# What is an error in my PHP code of login using cookie?

Tags: php, html, cookies

Here I am using static value user1 for login and password. But the code is not working properly. The web browser is also not storing cookie value. I tried but could not find the error in the code. I tried to run this code from different machines.  But it is not working. I am new at PHP and learning cookies and session.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pword"><br>
Remember me: <input type="checkbox" name="yes" value="1"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$un="user1";
$pw="user1";
$cb="1";

if(isset($_POST["uname"]) && isset($_POST["pword"]))
    {
        if($_POST["uname"]==$un && $_POST["pword"]==$pw)
        {
            if(isset($_COOKIE["visit"]) && isset($_COOKIE["visit"])==$uname)
            {
                echo "You are alredy logged in";
            }

            elseif($_POST["yes"]==$cb)
                {
                    echo "Cookie is set for two minutes";
                    setcookie('visit','$_POST["uname"]',time()+120);

                }

            else
                {
                    echo "Cookie is set for a minute";
                    setcookie('visit','$_POST["uname"]',time()+60);
                }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Username/Password invalid";
        }   
    }
else
{
    echo "You must supply usename and password";
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a **weak hash like MD5 or SHA**.

Comment: `$_COOKIE['$un']` will never works, because `$un` is not interpreted in single quotes.

Comment: @tadman I'm agree with your warning, but users could learn about it. And then, understand why it is better to use a framework for this. No?

Comment: Also you are setting a cookie named visit and not $un and you are setting it for 120 secs in any case

Comment: @Syscall Getting this absolutely correct is *really hard*, and anything less than that exposes you to severe risk. Would you trust an amateur to do open-heart surgery on you or install your home electrical system? Some things you can learn on the job, others you need a lot of formal training before you make your first real attempt. The [list of potential threats](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) is really long and knowing how to handle all of these requires years of exposure, training, and discipline. While learning is important, security is even more important.

Comment: @vivek : what does it print ?

Comment: @Syscall OK. I have corrected it.

Comment: @mplungjan  Modified it.

Comment: But you are NOT setting a cookie called the content of uname - you set a cookie called visit

Comment: You are doing `if(isset($_COOKIE["user1"]))` instead of `if(isset($_COOKIE["visit"]) && $_COOKIE["visit"]==$uname)` no?

Comment: @mplungjan I have modified it but still not working properly

Comment: Think about it - I did not fix it, just point out where to look

Comment: Now it is working properly. Thank all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : instead of

```
isset($_COOKIE["visit"])==$uname
```

it should be

```
isset($_COOKIE["visit"])==$un
```

in the condition.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer if it helped you.